# How do I move my navigation on my teamsite on SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, navigation, team-sites

I would like to know how I can move my navigation bar to sit under links on my teamsite. Navigation bar is using custom CSS code and it is using script editor to add in code on webpart and deploy it onto the page.

[image]

Comment: under links! Which Links?

Comment: @M.Qassas intranet link etc